# Why I am getting errors of type not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code for the app

```
import React from 'react'
import Wrapper from './Wrapper'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
const Products = () => {
    const [productsAvail, setProducts] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch('http://localhost:3004/products')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setProducts(data);
            console.log("hi", data);
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <Wrapper>
           <table>
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>ID</th>
                       <th>Title</th>
                       <th>Image</th>
                       <th>Actions</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  

                       {
                           productsAvail.map(product => {
                             return (
                                 <tr key={product.id}>
                                     <td>{product.title}</td>
                                 </tr>
                             )  
                           })
                       }
                   
               </tbody>
           </table>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Products
```

I am able to print the consoles correctly but somehow its giving the following error:

Failed to compile
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
Occurred while linting E:\practise\mypractise\react\myapp\src\admin\components\Products.js:4

Comment: There is no access to any `type` property in your code. Is that the full error? Is there a verbose mode of your linter you could enable? Right now it _sounds_ as the linter itself crashed...

Comment: What is your `eslint` version? It seems this was a bug (either [this](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2804) or [this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9767)) that was fixed long ago already. Try updating your linter.